# Swift 2 programmatically setting title of dynamic tableview cell to upper left hand corner

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set the height of the cell with:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)-> CGFloat {}
```

I'm looking to position the title in the top.  Currently, the title of the cell sits in the middle, and as the cell gets larger, this looks more and more awkward as shown below.

[image]

Does anyone have ideas about how I could get the title to stay in the top left of the cell, no matter how big it stretches?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you adding the `UILabel`? In code or Interface Builder? Are you using constraints? If code, show the relevant pieces.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your storyboard->Editor->EmbededIn->Navigation Controller 
this will add additional view before your main view at storyBoard 
you can add Title and it will be always in top

If you are using label inside the cell as a title put it in the top left corner and press command,alt,shift ,= all in same time will do the constraints directly

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting his question. He wants to know how he can get the text in the colored views to be at the top of those views. Your answer does not address this.

Comment: If you are using label inside the cell as a title put it in the top left corner and press command,alt,shift ,= all in same time will do the constraints directly

Comment: That didn't work.  I already have a title in there, with stuff linked to it.  I need to make sure the title I have doesn't dilute when the cell grows.